# Quantization and evaluating a complex function on multiple Riemann sheets

Tags: complex-analysis, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

In [Lecture 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Sm7SNlNUOI) of his mathematical physics course, Carl Bender mentions that the evaluation of a complex function on multiple Riemann sheets can be used to describe the quantization of the laws of nature we observe.

How is this way of thinking about quantization connected to the usual methods of quantization applied in physics, such as for example covariant quantization, light-cone quantization, or BRST quantization ?